# Add a circle on a rectangle

Tags: d3.js

I want to add a black circle on a light blue rectangle, but this circle doesn't show on this rectangle, which is hidden by this rectangle.

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
        width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var rect_center = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("id","rect_center")
    .attr("width",width/4)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("x", margin.left*3+(width/2-width/4)/2)
    .attr("y", margin.top)
    .attr("fill", "#9ecae1");
rect_center.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", "192")
      .attr("cy", "174.5625")
      .attr("r", "5")
      .attr("fill", "black");
```

Comment: Could you please add more code, as I am unable to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Yes, I edit the code

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is trying to append the circle within the rectangle. However, svg doesn't allow this. You have to append the circle to the svg separately. See the code below.

```js
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
        width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var svg = d3.select('svg')
             .attr('width', width)
             .attr('height',height);
var rect_center = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("id","rect_center")
    .attr("width",width/4)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("x", margin.left*3+(width/2-width/4)/2)
    .attr("y", margin.top)
    .attr("fill", "#9ecae1");
var circle = svg.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", "192")
      .attr("cy", "174.5625")
      .attr("r", "5")
      .attr("fill", "black");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Actually, when I added a circle on a rectangle, the information of this circle was shown on the source of the html,  it just didn't display on the page. So I think this circle was under the rectangle.

Comment: The markup for the `circle` would be within the `<rect></rect>` tags and that is not acceptable in svg.

Comment: Please remember to mark this as answer, as it solves your problem.